# What determines how many skill points it takes to level up a skill?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

When leveling up, it will take either one or two points to level up a skill. I know it's related to how much the skill is used, but exactly what determines how many points are required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cost of improving a skill you level up depends on whether or not that skill has been used successfully on the previous character level. Skills that have been used successfully on the previous character level will only cost 1 skill point to improve, otherwise they will cost 2 skill points instead.

So basically you'll want to make sure you use all weapons and interactions you want to improve cheaply (with only 1 point) before you level up.

Source: Personal experience, [wiki](http://sword-of-the-stars-the-pit.wikia.com/wiki/Skills)

Comment: That's about how I figured it was. I keep forgetting there's a wiki...